# Cythonize: check if word in list of strings is a substring of another string

Tags: cython

I want to iterate over a list of input words `list_words` and check if any belongs to an input string.

I tried to cythonize the code but when I annotate it I see almost all of it in yellow, suggesting python interactions.

Not sure how I could speedup this:

```py
cpdef cy_check_any_word_is_substring(list_words, string):
    cdef unicode w
    cdef unicode s_lowered =  string.lower()
    for w in list_words:
        if w in s_lowered:
            return True
    return False
```

Example

```py
# all words in list_words are lower cased
list_words = ['cat', 'dog', 'eat', 'seat']
input_string = 'The animal saw the Dog and started to make noises'

# should return true
cy_check_any_word_is_substring(list_words, input_string)
```

Note I want to make the code work independently if characters are capitalized or not (that is why I do `string.lower()`), I assume the input list of words is already lowered.

#### Update

I wonder if a solution that uses C++ could be faster.
I don't know C++ though, I tried

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string

cpdef cy_check_any_word_is_substring(vector[string] list_words,string string):
    s_lowered =  string.lower()
    for w in list_words:
        if w in s_lowered:
            return True
    return False
```

But it produces the error

```
Invalid types for 'in' (string, Python object)
```

#### Update 2

I tried the following to avoid the error presented in the previous section `update`.

```py
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string,npos

cdef bint cy_check_w_substring(string s_lowered, vector[string] list_words):
    cdef string w
    for w in list_words:
        if s_lowered.find(w) !=npos:
            return True
    return False

cpdef cy3_check_any_word_is_substring(words_bytes, input_string):
    cdef bint result = False
    s_lowered =  input_string.lower()
    result = cy_check_w_substring(bytes(s_lowered, 'utf8'), words_bytes)
    return result
```

This can be used changing the original list of words as a list of bytes.

```py
# all words in list_words are lower cased
list_words = ['cat', 'dog', 'eat', 'seat']
list_words_bytes = [bytes(w,'utf8') for w in list_words]
input_string = 'The animal saw the Dog and started to make noises'

# should return true
cy3_check_any_word_is_substring(list_words_bytes, input_string)
```

Nevertheless this is much slower

```py
%%timeit
cy3_check_any_word_is_substring(list_words_bytes, input_string)
#1.01 µs ± 3.16 ns per loop
```

```py
%%timeit
cy_check_any_word_is_substring(list_words, input_string)
#190 ns ± 0.773 ns per loop
```

Note `cy3_check_any_word_is_substring` internally casts `s_lowered` as `bytes` but this already takes 145 ns which is almost the cost of `cy_check_any_word_is_substring` which makes this approach clearly not viable.

```
%%timeit
bytes(input_string, 'utf8')
#145 ns ± 0.55 ns per loop
```

Comment: The `cdef unicode` lines are probably slowing you down. I suspect they're just adding an extra type-check but not giving Cython much useful information that it can optimize with. I'm not convinced you can do much with Cython here though.

Comment: You are right, the cdef unicode is basically irrelevant. I wonder though if `list_words` could be typed so that the compiler knows that `w` is a string at compile time and can make use of this info to speed it up. Maybe as a C++ Vector ? My knowledge of C++ is almost non-existent.

Comment: The trouble with using a c++ vector is that you have to convert the entire Python list to the vector when you call it from Python. Which can often lose any speed up you get from C++. If you make it only callable from Cython and work with a vector input then it might be good

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem with the C++ solution is that if you pass it a Python iterable there's a hidden type conversion. So it has to iterate through the entire list and then convert every string to a C++ string. For this reason I doubt it'll give you much benefit.

If you can generate the data as a C++ vector without the type conversion then it may work better. For this you should use a `cdef` function instead of a `cpdef` function (I rarely like `cpdef` functions because they're usually the worst of both worlds).

The specific problems you have:

- The C++ string class does not have a `.lower()` function, so the line `s_lowered =  string.lower()` is implicitly converting it back to a Python bytes then calling `.lower()` on that. You'll have to implement `.lower` yourself (or convert to the C++ `string` *after* calling `.lower` on the Python object).
- `w in s_lowered` isn't implemented for C++ strings. You want `s_lowered.find(w) != npos` (where `npos` is `cimported` from `libcpp.string`).

Comment: I tried to call a function that does this logic after `.lower` is called, converting the lowered string into bytes. Just doing this takes too much time, making this approach not viable.

If I don't cast it to bytes (see `update 2` function `cy3_check_any_word_is_substring` calls  `bytes(s_lowered, 'utf8')`) then I get an error `TypeError: expected bytes, str found`.

Comment: Even if assuming `cy_check_w_substring` in `update 2` is implemented correctly, if there is no better way to cast the python strings to valid inputs for `cy3_check_any_word_is_substring` then it is just unreasonable to expect an overall speedup of the method, because as you mentioned copying/casting takes more time than the computation I want to do with those strings.